# XLSX custom date format read as String

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I have xlsx with this date in cell: `03-09-2014` when I read xlsx cell using apache POI, it writes this: `41883.0`.

This is the way how I do that:

```
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + ";");
            }
```

Since I have converted all cells to become type of String, I would expect no deformation of the date...

Any solution?
[apache poi DataFormatter on cell containing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891181/apache-poi-dataformatter-on-cell-containing-date)
This is the solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why? Why oh why oh why would you have written that code to start with? It's just wrong on so many levels, as covered by probably every third Apache POI question on Stackoverflow :( Oh, and it's [explicitly advised against in the JavaDocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)....

You have two options available to you. If you want to have full control of reading the values, then follow the [instructions in the Apache POI documentation on reading cell values](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents), and write code something like:

```
for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
        System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
        System.out.print(" - ");

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you just want "give me the closest string you can to what this cell looks like in Excel", then you need to use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), which provides methods which read the Excel format rules applied to a cell, then re-creates (as best it can) those in Java

Your code should be:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();

String valueAsInExcel = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
```

That will format the number based on the formatting rules applied in Excel, so should return it looking as you expect

Finally, Dates in excel are stored as floating point numbers since 1900 or 1904, which is why you see the number you do in the date cell.

Comment: I have checked stack overflow so stop being arrogant. Everything I found was how to convert it to date format, what I have tried and it returned me 00-00-000 00:00:00 Sun ... something like that. And MY question was, why I cant get normal String value from the cell. I know, the cell is numeric but if I set cell type to String, I would expect getting the date as String ...

Comment: FOI I didn't use word WHY.

Comment: Changing the cell type to string != fetching the nearest equivalent-to-excel formatting value as a string, they're totally different things

Comment: As, incidentally, the [JavaDocs for setCellType quite clearly state](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)...

Comment: Thank you, this one was great. You have my +1 and correct answer/